# Strange behaviour with Gamequery's collision function

Tags: jquery, collision, gamequery

I'm trying to handle the collisions on a game with *collision()* but I don't understand what's going on. Here's a summary:

```
    $("#screen").playground({height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT, width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH});
$.playground().addSprite("wall",{animation:anim_mur, posx: 0, posy: -100, width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH, height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT+300})
    .addSprite("table",{animation:anim_tableau, posx: 459, posy: 122, width: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH, height: PLAYGROUND_HEIGHT});
$.playground().addGroup('enemies', {width: 320, height: 280}).end()
            .addSprite("sp_bed",{animation:anim_bed, posx: PLAYGROUND_WIDTH-400, posy: 210, width: 320, height: 280})
```

And then I handle the collisions there

```
$("#sp_viseur").collision("#enemies").each(function(){
    alert('test');
    });
```

And I fill the "enemies" group with sprites in another function.
I want the function to be called any time the "sp_viseur' sprite collides with a sprite of the "enemies" group. But the function is never called!
I ran a few more tests so I have question: how does the "collision" function work? Does it use the css attributes (left, top...) or the gamequery ones (posx,posy)?

Thanks.

PS: "sp_viseur" added to the playground like the other sprites.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I realized that my answer wasn't exactly what you asked for:

.collision() don't return collision with groups so you have to add to the .collision selector a class that will be applied to all your enemies sprites for example .collision('#enemies,.enemies'). Gamequery uses the posx and posy properties but if you use the .x() and  .y() functions they should  be synchronized.

Comment: Thank you! I found a way though with "#ennemies div"